# Trying to format JSON file with Python in Vim throws error

Tags: python, json, vim

I have a JSON file that I opened with Vim and want to format to make it a bit more readable.

I followed the advice of many Stack Overflow answers and other blog posts, and ran the command:

```
:%!python -m json.tool
```

After running this command the Vim prompts me to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or enter a command, and when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I get the following message highlighted in red:

```
Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640
```

The link that's shown leads me to Python 3.8 in Microsoft Store which is a little strange to me.

Why is this error occurring and what can I do to simply format my JSON file? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have python installed and added to the PATH environment variable?

Comment: Yes, I've made sure those are in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have python installed on your computer?
This command:

```
:%!python -m json.tool
```

uses python from the operative systems and passes the info from your JSON as a parameter. Run the following from the terminal, it should print the current version of python:

```
python --version
```

Assuming you have python installed, and since the vim code is correct, are you running vim on a simulator i.e VS Code? the issue might be related to the environment variables.

Comment: Yes, I have Python installed and running `python --version` returns `Python 3.7.4`. I'm not running it on a simulator, I'm right-clicking the JSON file and selecting "Edit with Vim."

Comment: can you show the output of `:echo $PATH` and verify the path is including the folder where python is installed? you can check python root folder running this from the terminal `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Comment: Apparently there was a conflict between the Anaconda Python I had installed and the system Python. I uninstalled the system one and set the path correctly.